# NSWindow not showing?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I've the following code :

```
NSRect contentRect = NSZeroRect;
contentRect.size = NSMakeSize(400, 400);
contentRect.origin = NSMakePoint(400, 400);

NSWindow* window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];


[window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
[window setMovableByWindowBackground:NO];
[window setExcludedFromWindowsMenu:YES];
[window setAlphaValue:0.8];
[window setOpaque:NO];
[window setHasShadow:YES];
[window useOptimizedDrawing:YES];

[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

It's called by `- (BOOL) applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)theApplication hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag`. This function is called when clicking on the Dock icon.

Why is my window not showing  ?

I also noticed that, when clicking dozen on times on the dock icon. Sometime I see my window appear for 1/10th a sec. Then it disappear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using ARC,

Then make `window` as property for the class. It will be solved as in this case it is getting released.

Use :

`@property(strong) NSWindow* window;`